# Track down very slow script

Tags: php, performance, caching, facebook-graph-api, photo

I'm using an easy way to display my Facebook pictures on my website. It's called [Facebook Album Gallery](http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-album-gallery/400462) and it's from [CodeCanyon](http://codecanyon.net/).

Although they claim to cache the data and [their example](http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-album-gallery/full_screen_preview/400462) is rather fast (5 sec.), [mine](http://www.dejeuzel.be/new/index.php?page=fotos) is very slow (15-20sec.) compared to theirs.

Is their a way to improve the loading speed or is there any way to find out why my page is loading slow and the example isn't...
I'm not familiar with caching, so if there is any more information you need, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug has a [profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler). Try it to determine where is the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

- First of from my connection the photo's/website loaded pretty fast.
- If PHP is the problem then Xdebug's profiler like Elszo pointed out could help you find it. Doubt that is the problem right now..
- Test your site using [Yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)/[Google Page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)  and read up on their information.
- If javascript is the problem use Javascript profiler like for example Firebug or Google Chrome's built in profiler.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I think I found the solution. In my PHP-code I was building a variable and the script kept adding information to the variable (`$html .= ...`) and only when the script was finished, it returned the variable. Now, I `echo` the results right away, which results in a faster loading process (the users sees the images popping up as soon as they are loaded). I don't know if it's good PHP code, probably not, but it's a lot faster!

Comment: Then you should accept this or another answer so that this topic can be closed :P!

Answer (score 0):

- You're displaying alot more photos then the example.
- Your server might be slower.
- Your images might be bigger then the one used in the example.

And make sure you are implementing the code properly and you are enabling caching, i don't really know how their code works, look for an FAQ or some documentation.